# How to include OSXFUSE and SSHFS into my Cocoa app Distribution?

Tags: cocoa, sshfs, osxfuse, packageinstaller

I'm creating a Cocoa Application using `SSHFS` but I want to make a package installer when user install, it will install `OSXFuse` and `SSHFS` to their macbook. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Installing OSXFuse means simply copying several files go global locations, which requires admin privileges. Its not that simple actually, since there's a handful of stuff to copy, but its very doable.

What you need to do is hold a copy of the following files with your app, and copy it to the destination using the installer (you must have it before running your app itself or it may crash).

List of files/folders to copy:

```
/Library/Frameworks/OSXFUSE.framework
/Library/Filesystems/osxfusefs.fs
/usr/local/include/osxfuse
/usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.2.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i32.la
/usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.la
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc
```

Note that you will also have to create some symbolic links in `/usr/local/lib/` and in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`. If you actually get to doing it and need help, let me know.

Using [PackageMaker](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html) that is rather simple.

In order to get a copy of the mentioned files and folders, you could install [OSXFuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and copy it yourself from the mentioned locations.

Reference:
https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ#12-what-is-osxfuse-versiondmg